# Spring JDBC Limit Query Length

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I am executing a custom built DML statement using the

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, valueMap);
```

call, where the `sql` is built based on the values in the map. Here my map could get very large and thus the sql might also get very lengthy. I understand that in Oracle, there is no fixed number for how long a query can be and there are many factors including the database configuration that may affect this value, but I would like to limit the query length to a fixed number.

What is the best way to limit the query length? Would the spring-batch API be any useful here?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: How does your SQL looks like? (give us example) Are you sure that you can't use batch operations like http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/?

Comment: It is actually a Merge statement. The number of columns are dynamic and the Using clause is built based on this number. Additionally, this clause also contains unions depending on the input list size. It looks like this -

Comment: I can't seem to get my comment submission with the sql to work here but let me give another try.

Comment: FYI: If you can't edit the question then you can use services like http://ctrlv.it/ and just post link here.

Comment: Here's how the query looks like - http://pastebin.com/qPERC6Ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose one of these approaches:

1. Temporary table - Insert data in batch to the temporary table and then use MERGE INTO statement with that table.
2. Create SQL type for your rows and bind just that one parameter. (google for OraData - it is a bit tricky but it works)

Both will enable you to have a small static query and therefore avoid potential problems with too large query (and its parsing, polluting library cache etc.).